# Tumblr: Code for displaying full size images when clicking on it

Tags: javascript, css, image, tumblr

I've installed a new Tumblr theme, and noticed that if I click on posted images, it never shows the full size image.

#### Problem

First click on image - shows the post singled out. Normal sized image.
Second click in singled out mode - Just reloads the page.

#### Expectation

First click on image - loads up original full size image without any styling (just the plain image so it can be viewed/downloaded)

I think the solution is some option in this part of the code.

---

/* GENERAL  */

```
        #infscr-loading {
            display: none;
            opacity: 0; 
        } 
    
        #content {
            width: 850px; 
            height: 100%; 
            position: relative;
            left: 5%; 
            margin-left: 350px; 
            font-family: {font:Text}; 
            {block:ifRightSidebar}
            margin-left:  -450px; 
            {/block:ifRightSidebar}
      
            margin-top: 81px; 
      
        }
        
        #content a{
            color: #000; /* color:Link */
            text-decoration: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2);
        }

        #description a {
            color: {color:Description}; /* color:Link */
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        
        #overlayer {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: -1;
            top: 0px;
            height: 100%; 
            background-color: #FFF; 
            padding-left: 20px; 
            padding-right: 20px; 
            left: calc(50% - {select:Content Size}/2 - 20px); 
            width: {select:Content Size};
        }
        
        /* GENERAL POST */ 
        
        #content .post {
            background: #EFB576; /* color:Post Background */
            color: {color:Text}; /* color:Text */ 
            width: 100%; 
            word-wrap: break-word;
            overflow: hidden; 
            position: relative;
            font-size: {select:Text Size} /* select:Font Size */;
            padding: 14px; 
            padding-bottom: 50px; 
            margin-top: 60px;
            margin-bottom: 60px; 
            {block:PermalinkPage}
            width: 470px !important;
            position: relative !important;
            left: 50% !important;
            margin-left: -250px !important; 
            margin-top: 0px !important;
            padding: 15px !important;
            {/block:PermalinkPage}
        }
        
        #content .post blockquote {
            display: block; 
            -webkit-margin-before: 5px !important;
            -webkit-margin-after: 5px !important;
            -webkit-margin-start: 8px !important;
            -webkit-margin-end: 8px !important;
            border-left: 3px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
            padding-left: 10px; 
            top: 3px; 
            position: relative;
        }
        
        #content .post a{
            color: {color:Link}; /* color:Link */
            text-decoration: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2);
        }
        
        #content .post img {
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
        }
```

Comment: Post the link of your blog, and the code you have posted is just the CSS. The problem is more `JavaScript`-related.

Comment: Thank you for your reply =)

I created a new blog with the same code since the original one is nsfw.
http://demo1234a.tumblr.com/

There you can see the problem. No matter what I do the uploaded test file can´t be viewed in it´s original size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the overflow under

```
 #content .post { 
   ....
 }
```

from hidden to visible. If you look on CSS overflow property on w3schools, it will explain more about it. That might be the problem! Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply =)

I changed all hidden values to visible, but it had no effect on the tumblr theme. 
It seems that´s not what´s wrong with it~

I created a demo account with the code. Maybe that helps?
http://demo1234a.tumblr.com/

Thank you for your time! ><